# How do I make VS Code regconize my package?

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm

I have a package that i publish to npm, but when I install the package and try to write the component (that I exported in my package), VS Code does not suggest auto-import the package. I still can mannualy import the component and use it normally.

I did declare the module with the exported components

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { BoxProps as BoxPropsFromPackage } from '../components/Box/Box';

declare module 'adgo' {
     export interface BoxProps extends BoxPropsFromPackage { }

     export const Box: React.FC<BoxProps>;
}
```